# Azure Bot dialog with if-else condition

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I'm using sample Azure MSGraph Bot Authentication (https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L112), without any code changes (only changing APP id's and connection name). Here is the part of code, that works for me wrong:

```cs
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> ProcessStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (stepContext.Result != null)
            {
                var tokenResponse = stepContext.Result as TokenResponse;

                if (tokenResponse?.Token != null)
                {
                    var parts = ((string)stepContext.Values["command"] ?? string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant().Split(' ');

                    var command = parts[0];

                    if (command == "me")
                    {
                        await OAuthHelpers.ListMeAsync(stepContext.Context, tokenResponse);
                    }
                    else if (command.StartsWith("send"))
                    {
                        await OAuthHelpers.SendMailAsync(stepContext.Context, tokenResponse, parts[1]);
                    }
                    else if (command.StartsWith("recent"))
                    {
                        await OAuthHelpers.ListRecentMailAsync(stepContext.Context, tokenResponse);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Your token is: {tokenResponse.Token}"), cancellationToken);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("We couldn't log you in. Please try again later."), cancellationToken);
            }

            return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
```

When I'm typing "me" command,  receive my credentials. After that I'm typing another command (for example, "recent"), and bot welcomes me again. I think this can be because of ProcessStepAsync method calls only once, and then dialog returns to first step. But I want bot to return to if/else dialog every time it receives command from me.

In other words, how can I change turn of dialog, so it will back to ProcessStepAsync again, when i'm typing command?

Comment: Was the problem resolved? Let me know your update.

Comment: Sure, i'll let you know as soon as i'll try the solution, thanks

Comment: That's sounds good, have a great coding time 

Answer (score 1):

In that case you have to do it while you taking input from user and have to check that input like given format. I would recommend you `switch-case` rather monotonous if-else block.

Try like this:

```
 dynamic checkUserInput = turnContext.Activity.Text;

                //Check Each User Input
                switch (checkUserInput.ToLower())
                {
                    case "me":
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You have typed me"), cancellationToken);

                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Once you begin using solution workspace, you'll see checklist that will be help you too:"), cancellationToken);
                        //You can add any additional flow here if needed
                        var overview = OverViewFlow();
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(overview).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        break;
                    case "send":
                          await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You have typed send"), cancellationToken);
                         break;
                      default: //When nothing found in user intent
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("What are you looking for?"), cancellationToken);
                        break;

                }
```

Though Its not essential but I am showing you how you could make the things done.

```
 public IMessageActivity OverViewFlow()
        {
            try
            {
                var replyToConversation = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
                replyToConversation.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
                replyToConversation.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

                Dictionary<string, string> cardContentList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                cardContentList.Add("Link 1", "https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fffC/O");
                cardContentList.Add("Link 2", "https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fffC/O");
                cardContentList.Add("Link 3", "https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fffC/O");

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> cardContent in cardContentList)
                {
                    List<CardImage> cardImages = new List<CardImage>();
                    cardImages.Add(new CardImage(url: cardContent.Value));

                    List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();

                    CardAction plButton = new CardAction()
                    {
                        Value = $"",
                        Type = "imBack",
                        Title = "" + cardContent.Key + ""
                    };

                    cardButtons.Add(plButton);

                    HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
                    {
                        Title = $"",
                        Subtitle = $"",
                        Images = cardImages,
                        Buttons = cardButtons
                    };

                    Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
                    replyToConversation.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
                }

                return replyToConversation;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
            }
        }
```

Hope it would help you.

Comment: where should i paste this code? If i paste it in ProcessStepAsync method, i see the same behaviour - after first command, all dialog returns to LoginStepAsync method. And i get an error by the way:

"Self referencing loop detected for property 'module' with type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'. Path 'context.adapter.onTurnError.method.module.assembly.entryPoint

Comment: On program entry point. I have put that inside `protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`  as its my bot entry point

Comment: It works :) But now the login step is skipped, and i can do stuff without authentication. How can i pass login step (loginStepAsync in MainDialog.cs) before any case in switch block?

Comment: Just put the login flow at first, then check token each time if token valid then skip token flow and redirect to your expected flow many way around that may be , would be great if there is code so that easy to solve, no worry I am here solve together ^^

Comment: But the login step is in MainDialog class with its own logic and parameters (and tokenResponse is in WaterFallStepContext). How can i access it from DialogBot.cs?

Comment: In other words, how can i pass token from MainDialog.cs to OnMessageActivityAsync (the code is here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L112)

Comment: I would say that there is one more problem now :) I described this in the comments above.